# Run function on html loaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If i load a html document in to a div tag for example, is there any way to call a function that i know exists in the loaded html?

Something like this:

```
$('#foo').load('bar.html', function(){
    //call a function in bar.html
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put your JS code in separate file (you load it in your loaded html file) and use [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) like this:

```
$('#foo').load('bar.html', function(){
    $.getScript("js/fileName.js");
    // call a function from fileName.js
});
```

So create a separate JS file (good practice not to mix with html or html document) and call it inside your bar.html file:

```
<script href="js/fileName.js"></script>
```

With this, you can also get that file to work with load using `getScript`.

Comment: Thanks, i know that calling the function directly in the load callback would work, but i suppose thats bad practice :)